# c++ rand() different behaviour within struct

Tags: c++, random, struct

I have noticed strange behaviour from `rand()`when it is used within a struct. 
The code below uses the same expression to get a double between 0 and 1. 
The values generated in the `std::cout << ( (double) rand() / RAND_MAX ) <<std::endl;` statement seem to be random and are distributed over the specified range. The values that are assigned to the struct's `x` and `y` variables, don't seem to be distributed the same way. 
e.g. running the program 4 times produces `[0.96516, 0.965629, 0.965731, 0.965817]` for `one.x`.

Is there an explanation to this?

Note: I'm not interested in other libraries or workarounds. I'd just like to understand why rand() does behave so differently.

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

struct particle {
    double x = ( (double) rand() / RAND_MAX );
    double y = ( (double) rand() / RAND_MAX );
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand( (int) time(NULL) );
    particle one;
    std::cout << one.x <<std::endl;
    std::cout << ( (double) rand() / RAND_MAX ) <<std::endl;
};
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need those outermost parentheses around the calculations that use `rand()`. Also, do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Did you try moving the position of the `struct` definition and its print statement? Maybe the random number generator was warming up?

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right. the parentheses are not necessary. I'm not sure how you combine a calculated number with '\n'. can you show me? Neither of this explains the problem though.

Comment: I failed to reproduce your results. That's the thing with _random_ things. They may not _feel_ random, even when they are.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this using `GCC 7.1.0`on `Linux`. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Doesn't seem to reproduce http://ideone.com/i9IuSE

Comment: Or did you run them in quick succession because seeding with `std::time(0)` only changes the seed by `1` once a second. Not a lot of variation for a potentially fairly rubbish random number generator like `rand()`.

Comment: My guess is that your implementation of rand gives tight results for tight seed values so since you run the program 4 times in a row the time doesn't change much so the seed doesn't change much so the results don't change much.  If you want random numbers use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)

Comment: Cannot reproduce using C++ 14 on ideone.com

Comment: Cannot reproduce using C++17, gcc 7.1.1

Comment: @Galik thanks. I have swapped the lines like this: `int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand( (int) time(NULL) );
    std::cout <<  (double) rand() / RAND_MAX  <<std::endl;
    particle one;
    std::cout << one.x <<std::endl;
};` and it does work!!! why is that???

Comment: @tr909 I wasn't expecting that to "fix" anything tbh I was just expecting it to produce the badly distributed values from the open statement rather than from the `struct`.

Comment: Also: if i just call `rand()` first in the `main()` it seems to behave. I'm useing xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Thanks everybody. I promise next time I try it with a different compiler first. @Galik you have raised the question of the compiler first. which I guess solved the problem. it you post it as an answer ill accept it.

Comment: To be honest I suspect this is just an artifact of `rand()` not being a particularly good implementation. The `C++` standard makes very few (if any) guarantees about its quality which is why it is recommended to use the new standard `<random>` features. I don't think it's worth posting an answer for tbh.